# Split text on separator in cells in different rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I've input data like this:

```
| VR headsets          |
| -------------------- |
| htc;oculus;cardboard |
| playstation vr       |
| htc;oculus           |
| no                   |
| daydream;cardboard   |
| cardboard            |
| no                   |
```

Each new line in input example above, is a new row and each one is one column. My question is now: How could I spit all cells at the separator *(`;`)* in Excel 2016? Is there a formule for this?

**Note:** The input file is not a CSV file! It's a `.xlsx` file that contains results of a survey. The input data above is just one question of it.

Finaly I would data like this

```
| VR headsets          |
| -------------------- |
| htc                  |
| oculus               |
| cardboard            |
| playstation vr       |
| htc                  |
| oculus               |
| no                   |
| daydream             | 
| cardboard            |
| cardboard            |
| no                   |
```

Can be in multiple columns.

I've tried to use this formula:

```
=DEEL('Alle data'!$U4; KOLOMMEN('Alle data'!$U4:'Alle data'!$U4); B$2)
```

In English *(could be wrong)*

```
=PART('Alle data'!$U4; COLUMNS('Alle data'!$U4:'Alle data'!$U4); B$2)
```

but I've this result

[image]

In the cells `B$2` stand this values:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in column **A**, running this short VBA macro:

```
Sub MakeList()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, j As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 1

    For i = 1 To N
        ary = Split(Cells(i, 1), ";")
        For Each a In ary
            Cells(j, 2) = a
            j = j + 1
        Next a
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

To use this you will have to make the file ***.xlsm*** rather than ***.xlsx***